# Simple microscope but tangling doubt!

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, microscopy

My textbook (NCERT optics Class 12 pg 339) on simple convex lens microscope says,

> The idea is to get an erect, magnified and
>   virtual image of the object at a distance so that it
>   can be viewed comfortably, i.e., at 25 cm or more.
>   If the object is at a distance f, the image is at
>   infinity. However, if the object is at a distance
>   slightly less than the focal length of the lens, the
>   image is virtual and closer than infinity. Although
>   the closest comfortable distance for viewing the
>   image is when it is at the near point (distance
>   D ≅ 25 cm), it causes some strain on the eye.
>   Therefore, **the image formed at infinity is often
>   considered most suitable for viewing by the relaxed
>   eye**.

What would it mean that image at infinity can be seen? I can not visualise this.

Comment: Infinity here just means a point far enough such that the light coming from any object at that point or beyond are parallel (almost) to your eye.

Comment: When you're looking at anything farther away than a few hundred meters, it's infinity as near as your eyes can tell.  The stars are easily visible if your eyes are good, and they are essentially at infinity.